# Merging two columns from Google Sheets into this confusing data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, gmplot

I'm pulling two columns from Google Sheets. They contain lat/long information. I can print them just fine with this code:

```
x1 = [item1 for item1 in wks.col_values(3) if item1]
for item1 in x1[1:]:
    print(item1)
    print(Decimal(item1))

x2 = [item2 for item2 in wks.col_values(4) if item2]
for item2 in x2[1:]:
    print(item2)
    print(Decimal(item2))
```

output:

```
39.204345
39.204345
39.204345
39.204345
39.602555
39.602555
39.802999
39.802999
-76.67478
-76.67478
-76.674806
-76.674806
-76.674822
-76.674822
-76.374822
-76.374822
```

How can I get all of these values and any future values to work with this type of data structure?:

```
latitude, longitude = zip(*[
    (37.769901, -122.498331),
    (37.768645, -122.475328),
    (37.771478, -122.468677),
    (37.769867, -122.466102),
    (37.767187, -122.467496),
    (37.770104, -122.470436)
])
```

In other words, is there a way to pull both columns lat and long, and zip them like above? This is for use with gmplot.

edit: additional errors. nothing but errors. tried this so many different ways....

```
latitude = int(float(wks.col_values(3)))
longitude = int(float(wks.col_values(4)))
##latitude, longitude = np.ndarray(*zip(x1[1:], x2[1:]))

apikey = '' # (your API key here)
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.766956, -122.448481, 14, apikey=apikey)
gmap.scatter(latitude, longitude, color='#FF0000', size=75, marker=False)
gmap.draw('newmap.html')



TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that `x1` and `x2` have the same length, you could say:

```
latitude, longitude = zip(*[(x1[i], x2[i]) for i in range(1,len(x1) - 1)])
```

Alternatively, you can use slice notation and not worry about lengths:

```
latitude, longitude = zip(*zip(x1[1:], x2[1:]))
```

Comment: hmmm any idea how to get around this?: in get_cycle
    lat1 = (math.pi / 180.0) * lat
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: `tuple([math.pi * x / 180.0 for x in lat])`

Comment: I suggest you check out numpy. The numpy.ndarray arrays work in the way you tried; it multiplies each element by the float value and returns another ndarray type object with the correspoding results.

Comment: Also, the error happens because the interpreter is suggesting that you might wanna copy  the sequence (in this case, a tuple) an int number of times (like when 3*"hey" gives you "heyheyhey", only in that case the sequence is a string) but it found a float instead. I believe that you want to convert degs to rads, so I recommend using numpy!

Comment: Just getting flooded with more crazy errors: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-72.942747'  C_C

Comment: import math 
latitude = (np.asarray(wks.col_values(3)))
print(tuple([math.pi * x / 180.0 for x in latitude]))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):
- _Return an integer object constructed from a number or string `x`, or return 0 if no arguments are given._
- _If x defines `__trunc__()`, it returns `x.__trunc__()`. **For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.**_
- _If x is not a number or if base is given, then **x must be a string** (...) instance representing **an integer literal in radix base**._

Comment: i.e. can't do `int('-72.942747')` but you can do `int(float('-72.942747'))`

Comment: I'm really bad at this:
latitude = int(float(wks.col_values(3)))
print(tuple([math.pi * x / 180.0 for x in latitude]))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: This actually works!!! latitude = list(map(float, wks.col_values(3)))  However... My first row value is the text "string" and ends up with this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Latitude'. Do you know how to ignore the first row?

Comment: you can use slice notation to get rid of the first element `list(map(float, wks.col_values(3)[1:]))`

Comment: Ah. I tried that and failed earlier because I put it as list(map(float, wks.col_values(3[1:])). Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: To get the result you want with numpy, it'd have to be something like `(math.pi / 180.0) * np.array([*map(float, wks.col_values(3)[1:])])`