# Is there any way to pass letters to this library expecting a tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, data-structures, tuples

I'm pulling data from google sheet columns like so:

```
latitude = list(map(float, wks.col_values(3)[1:]))
longitude = list(map(float, wks.col_values(4)[1:]))
name = list(map(float, wks.col_values(2)[1:]))
```

I use this loop to access my list:

```
for x,y in enumerate(latitude):
    gmap.marker(latitude[x], longitude[x], title=name[x])
```

name will only pass if the cells contain numbers only. If I have a single letter anywhere in any column, my map is never generated. I don't even see an error. I'm using gmplot to generate my .html map. Is there any way to get text to pass here?

Comment: Why do you convert names to `float`? On a side note, a proper way to iterate through three parallel lists is to use `zip`, not `enumerate`.

Comment: I think that's the only way to pass my coordinates from Google earth to gmplot. I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503776/merging-two-columns-from-google-sheets-into-this-confusing-data-structure/62503930?noredirect=1#comment110561421_62503930

Comment: But `name` is not coordinates, is it?

Comment: no it's not. name is text. for example: John. Will using zip allow me to pass my coordinates along with strings? If so, do you know how to zip my columns?

Comment: uhh wait i think i got it...         name = (wks.col_values(2)[1:])
        print(name)..... that was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
name = (wks.col_values(2)[1:]) 
print(name)
```

doesn't need to be a float. :|